# Argument Validator (Me vs Calculator)

Tags: logic

So, I have finished my assigment about Validating Argument

The Question:

```
(¬p∨¬q)→(r∧s)
r→t
¬t
__________
∴p
```

My Answer:

```
(p→¬q)→r (because p∨¬q ≡ p→q and (r^s) → r)
r→t
__________
p→t (Syllogism)
¬t
__________
¬p (Tollens)

(The Argument is Not Valid)
```

I try to validate using Online Calculator and I get my answer wrong (The argument is Valid)

[https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(p%E2%86%92%C2%ACq)%E2%86%92(r%E2%88%A7s),%20r%E2%86%92t,%20%C2%ACt%20|=%20p](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(p%E2%86%92%C2%ACq)%E2%86%92(r%E2%88%A7s),%20r%E2%86%92t,%20%C2%ACt%20%7C=%20p)

[Here is The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArcTK.png)

I need help to explain what's wrong, because I'm confusing on this chapter

Thank you before..

Comment: How did you conclude $p\to t$? I believe you can only conclude $(p\to\lnot q)\to t$ and subsequently $\lnot(p\to\lnot q)$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Before comment I understand (p→¬q)→t same as p→¬q→t. After comment I remember if p→¬q in the bracket. So, that is my answer's wrong?

Comment: This step is definitely wrong. I also fail to see, even if $(p\to\lnot q)\to t$ *was* the same as $p\to(\lnot q\to t)$, how that would help... $t$ being false would not preclude, say, $q$ being true, in which the RHS is true and $p$ can be anything.

Comment: @StinkingBishop okay, I undestand it and I have wrong.. Thank you very much